# How to query two fields on same nested document

Tags: mongodb

How can I get only second document, that have child `{"name": "Harry", "age": 20}`.

I tried query `db.items.find({"children.name": "Harry", "children.age": 20})`, but it searches for single field match instead of both in children

```
[
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Harry",
        "age": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "Dmitry",
        "age": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Harry",
        "age": 20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match array elements.

Comment: @turivishal Add an answer please, so I can select it as right one

Comment: this is common question and lot of similar questions so I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        {
            "children":
            {
                $elemMatch:
                {
                    "name": "Harry",
                    "age": 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```